# Hikvision IP PTZ camera control with LabVIEW

Tags: c++, labview

I want to control hikvision camera with LabVIEW.

- By using the "NET_DVR_RealPlay_V30" function of the "HCNETSDK.dll" file compiled with C/C++ with "Call Library Function" in LabVIEW, I can log in to the camera and read its information. However, the "NET_DVR_RealPlay_V40" function of HCNETSDK.dll requires a callback to transfer live stream data. There should be a search function. However, implementing a callback in LabVIEW is not that easy and causes some problems. In addition to HCNETSEDK.dll, I need to write a small wrapper DLL that will receive the Data and pass it to LabVIEW with the PostLVUserEvent function, and then I can capture these events in the Event Structure in LabVIEW.

  ```
   typedef void( CALLBACK * REALDATACALLBACK )(
    LONG lReal Handle,
    DWORD dwDataType ,
    BYTE * pBuffer ,
    DWORD dwBufSize , void * pUser
   );
  ```

  I know I need to export in the prototype above but I can't figure out how to adapt it exactly to C++ code. Can anyone help with this?

For a better understanding of the situation, I have attached a picture of the sample code I created in LabVIEW.
[image]

Thanks in advance for any help you can get.